# Gulp prompt before running a task

Tags: javascript, gulp

Id like to prompt the user before running the main `build` task at the bottom. I was looking at gulp-prompt as a solution but cant figure out how to implement it before any of the tasks run. I want the user to be able to cancel the entire `build` task before anything runs. Is that possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure how to implement the `.pipe(prompt.confirm())`

```
gulp.src('test.js')
  .pipe(prompt.confirm())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
```

Here is the entire gulp file

```
'use strict';

var gulp      = require('gulp');
var config    = require('../config');
var concat    = require('gulp-concat');
var unzip     = require('gulp-unzip');
var minimatch = require('minimatch');
var prompt    = require('gulp-prompt');
var notify    = require('gulp-notify');
var gutil     = require('gulp-util');

/**
 * Build Initial Project File Structure
 *  Docs: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support
 *  Order of Build:
 *      1. 'buildSass': Builds the ./sass directory in root
 *      2. 'buildFonts': Extracts the fonts from .zip and places them in ./fonts directory
 *      3. 'buildFontsCss': Extracts the fonts .css from .zip, concats all.css and places them in ./sass/typography/_fonts.scss directory
 *      4. 'buildJS': Builds the ./js directory in root
 *      5. 'moveCustomJSFiles': Places all js files (from wp _underscore theme) in proper directories
 *      6. run 'gulp build' in terminal to run all 5 tasks in the proper order and create the initial setup for your project
 */

gulp.task('buildSass', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.build.sass.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.sass.dest))
    return stream
        .on('end', function(){ gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgGreen('buildSass Compiled Successfully!')); });
});

gulp.task('buildFonts', ['buildSass'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.build.fonts.src)
        .pipe(unzip({
            filter: function(entry) {
                return minimatch(entry.path, config.build.fonts.include)
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.fonts.dest))
    return stream
        .on('end', function(){ gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgGreen('buildFonts Compiled Successfully!')); });
});

gulp.task('buildFontsCss', ['buildFonts'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.build.fonts.css.src)
        .pipe(unzip({
            filter: function(entry) {
                return minimatch(entry.path, config.build.fonts.css.include)
            }
        }))
        .pipe(concat(config.file.name.fontsSass))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.fonts.css.dest))
    return stream
        .on('end', function(){ gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgGreen('buildFontsCss Compiled Successfully!')); });
});

gulp.task('buildJS', ['buildFontsCss'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.build.js.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.js.dest))
    return stream
        .on('end', function(){ gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgGreen('buildJS Compiled Successfully!')); });
});

gulp.task('moveCustomJSFiles', ['buildJS'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.build.copyJS.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.copyJS.dest))
    return stream
        .on('end', function(){ gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgGreen('moveCustomJSFiles Compiled Successfully!')); })
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Project Build was successful! ✅', onLast: true }));
});

gulp.task('build', ['buildSass', 'buildFonts', 'buildFontsCss', 'buildJS', 'moveCustomJSFiles']);

// TODO:
// put confirm before run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [readline-sync](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync). I'm sure others will disagree, but prompts are one of those things that often work better when used synchronously IMO.

EDIT:

Here's how you would do it based on your code with gulp v4:

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
  function(done) {
    if (readlineSync.keyInYN('Do you want to build?')) {
      return done();
    }
    console.log('Ok, not building.');
    process.exit(1);
  },
  gulp.parallel(
    'buildSass',
    'buildFonts',
    'buildFontsCss',
    'buildJS',
    'moveCustomJSFiles'
  )
));
```

With gulp version <4, you can use the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) module instead of gulp.series:

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task('build-prompt', function(done) {
  if (readlineSync.keyInYN('Do you want to build?')) {
    return done();
  }
  console.log('Ok, not building.');
  process.exit(1);
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'build-prompt',
    [
      'buildSass',
      'buildFonts',
      'buildFontsCss',
      'buildJS',
      'moveCustomJSFiles'
    ],
    callback
  );
});
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what Im looking for however it looks like parallel and series aren't recognized in Gulp 3. I haven't upgraded to 4 yet. Getting this error `TypeError: gulp.parallel is not a function`

Comment: Gotcha. Pre-v4 you can use [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) instead of `gulp.series`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You are amazing my friend works beautifully! Thanks for the readline-sync sync heads up I haven't used that plugin before seems very useful!

Comment: no problem. don't forget to accept the answer if it works for ya, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prompt

I haven't tested this myself but the documentation indicates you can prompt the user with a confirmation message like "Continue?" and then optionally continue the task or not:

```
gulp.src('test.js')
    .pipe(prompt.confirm({
        message: 'Continue?',
        default: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
```

Comment: Thanks Jake yes this does work for a normal task but I could not figure out how to implement it on my build task. I read that prompt doesnt play well with streams and I have the tasks running in a certain order.